# How to format int to NSString with displaying the + sign for positive numbers in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, nsnumberformatter

AFAIK its impossible using just [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d"] since there is no specifiers for explicit displaying the + displaying, at least i didn't find it at [Apple Developer String Format Specifiers](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html)
So it looks like I have to use NSNumberFormatter in my case. I found how to set the plus sign representation but can't figure out how to achieve my goal. I tried

```
    NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    [numberFormatter setPositiveFormat:@"+0"];
    NSString strNumber = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:intSomeNumber]];
```

but I'm afraid it would cut numbers GT 9 to 1 digit and I don't want that. I just want to display any positive int with + and any negative with -. Is this the right way maybe:

```
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[numberFormatter setPositiveFormat:@"+#"];
NSString strNumber = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:intSomeNumber]];
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From the very page you linked:

> For more details, see the [IEEE printf specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/printf.html).

Now from the IEEE printf specification:

> +
>       The result of a signed conversion shall always begin with a sign ( '+' or '-' ). The conversion shall begin with a sign only when a
>   negative value is converted if this flag is not specified.

Example:

```
NSLog(@"%+f", 3.455677);
```

Result:

```
+3.455677
```

Answer (score 8):

```
[numberFormatter setPositivePrefix:@"+"];
```

Answer (score 7):

Use `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%+d", intSomeNumber]`

Answer (score 2):

Just use:

```
NSString *strNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%+d",intSomeNumber];
```

Comment: That's gonna be fun when the number is negative.